# Getting random repetitions when reading through a string via for loop

Tags: c, arrays, string, comparison, iteration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LINE 1000
#define MAX_QUERY 100

int read_lines(char line[MAX_LINE]);
int print_lines(char query[MAX_LINE]);

int
main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char query[MAX_QUERY];
    strcpy(query, argv[1]);
    printf("SO: query = %s\n", query);
    printf("---\n");
    print_lines(query);
    return 0;
}

int
read_lines(char line[MAX_LINE]){
    int line_len = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c == '\n'){
            break;
        }
        else{
            line[line_len] = c;
            line_len ++;
        }
    }
    line[line_len] = '\0';
    if(c == EOF && line_len == 0)
        return EOF;
    printf("%s\n",line);
    return line_len;
}

int
print_lines(char query [MAX_QUERY]){
    int line_num = 0;
    int query_len = strlen(query);
    int line_len = 0,i,y,z = 0, position,c = 0;
    int limit = query_len > line_len ? line_len : query_len;
    double score = 0, maximum;
    char score_list[15] = "";
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    while((line_len = read_lines(line)) != EOF){
        c = 0;
        line_num ++;
        printf("S1: line   %d, bytes = %d \n",line_num,line_len);
        /* Loops through the query and line and compares the characters
         * If it is the same, it adds to the score
         * Once it gets to different character the score is reset
         */
        for (i = 0; i < limit; i++){
            for (y = 0; y < limit; y++){
                if (query[i] == line[y]){
                    score++;
                }
                else if(score != 0 && query[i] != line[y]){
                    score_list[z] = score;
                    z++;
                }
            }
        }
        /* Finds the largest score in the array
         */
        maximum = score_list[0];
        for (position = 1; position < 15; position++){
            if (score_list[position] > maximum){
                maximum = score_list[position];
            }
        }
        /* resets the score list back to zero
         */
        while (c < 15){
            score_list[c] = 0;
            c++;
        }
        printf("S2: line   %d, score = %f\n",line_num,maximum); 
        printf("---\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the code reads a query which is for example, "fall down", and checks if it is in the lines and scores them according to how many characters match. However. I keep printing out only a 0 score and when I print the string through the loop, phrases get repeated where it should not be. my read_lines function reads a text file from stdin line by line and returns the byte size. How can I get the scoring to work and fix comparison loop?

Output should be

```
Down, down, down. Would the fall NEVER come to an end! 'I wonder how  
S1: line     1, bytes = 68  
S2: line     1, score =  5.000
---
many miles I've fallen by this time?' she said aloud. 'I must be getting  
S1: line     2, bytes = 72  
S2: line     2, score =  4.000
```

however I'm getting

```
SO: query = fall down
---
Down, down, down. Would the fall NEVER come to an end! 'I wonder how
S1: line   1, bytes = 68
line   1, score = 0.000000
---
many miles I've fallen by this time?' she said aloud. 'I must be getting
S1: line   2, bytes = 72
: line   2, score = 0.000000
---
```

If i print the line by the loop by adding printf("%c",line[y]), I get this output.

```
SO: query = fall down
---
Down, down, down. Would the fall NEVER come to an end! 'I wonder how
S1: line   1, bytes = 68
Down, down, down. Would the fall NEVER come tDown, down, down. Would the fall     NEVER come to an end! 'I wonder how                   °·) ⌠"" S2: line   1, score = 0.000000
---
many miles I've fallen by this time?' she said aloud. 'I must be getting
S1: line   2, bytes = 72
many miles I've fallen by this time?' shmany miles I've fallen by this time?' she said aloud. 'I must be getting           °·) ⌠""  S2: line   2, score =     0.000000
---

int
print_lines(char query [MAX_QUERY]){
    int line_num = 0;
    int query_len = strlen(query);
    int line_len = 0,i,y,z = 0, position,c = 0;
    int limit = query_len > line_len ? line_len : query_len;
    double score = 0, maximum;
    char score_list[15] = "";
    char line[MAX_LINE];
    while((line_len = read_lines(line)) != EOF){
        c = 0;
        line_num ++;
        printf("S1: line   %d, bytes = %d \n",line_num,line_len);
        /* Loops through the query and line and compares the characters
         * If it is the same, it adds to the score
         * Once it gets to different character the score is reset
         */
        for (i = 0; i < limit; i++){
            for (y = 0; y < limit; y++){
                if (query[i] == line[y]){
                    score++;
                }
                else if(score != 0 && query[i] != line[y]){
                    score_list[z] = score;
                    z++;
                }
            }
        }
        /* Finds the largest score in the array
         */
        maximum = score_list[0];
        for (position = 1; position < 15; position++){
            if (score_list[position] > maximum){
            maximum = score_list[position];
            }
        }
        /* resets the score list back to zero
         */
        while (c < 15){
            score_list[c] = 0;
            c++;
        }
        printf("S2: line   %d, score = %f\n",line_num,maximum); 
        printf("---\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provided compilable code — you're missing two close braces, I believe.  The signature of the `read_lines()` function that you're using is distressing; it has no way to know how big a buffer you are passing to it — we have to hope it knows about `MAX_LINE`, but it probably isn't a good design to restrict it so it assumes that size.  Are you sure you shouldn't have more functions for the code to use?  It certainly looks very busy.  The spaces before the `++` operators are disconcerting; they should normally be attached to the operand that is being incremented.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The spaces before the `++` operators are at least well defined. It would be a shame to tarnish good, functional advice with mere stylistic peer pressure.

Comment: Also, I'm not clear how your scoring is supposed to work.  It would be helpful if you gave a few (say 3) sample lines of input, and showed us what the score should be for the query string 'fall down' and how you determined that, and what score you actually get.  The 'when I print the string through the loop' comment is obscure: you should show us how you're doing that printing and show us what you mean by 'phrases get repeated' etc.  Please produce an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've added an example in the edit

Comment: Minor: Suggest  `line[line_len] = '\0';` before `if(c == EOF ...`

Comment: `maximum = score_list[0];` might use an uninitialized value of `score_list[0];`  `char score_list[15];` does not initialize anything.

Comment: (1) Where do you initialize maximum?  (2) Do you reset `score_list[]` to zeros for each line of input?  (3) How is the score `5` for the first line determined?  Is it because `fall ` (4 letters and a blank) match, and that's the longest match?  (4) How is the score `4` for the second line determined?  Is it because of `fall` again, but only 4 letters match `fallen`?  (5) Suppose the first line had 'would the dive NEVER end'; would the score be 4 (because 'down' matches and is 4 letters) or would it be 0 (because 'fall' doesn't match) — or some other value, and if so what and why?

Comment: @chux Sorry i don't understand, I'm still new to C. Shouldn't there be always something in the array. At least a 0?

Comment: @zkvsl: No; local variables that are not explicitly initialized contain junk.  Indeterminate values; you cannot reliably predict what they hold, but it isn't cryptographically random either — despite what SSL tried to do with such a buffer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler (1) I initialize the maximum before looping through the array to find the largest value. (2) Yes I reset the score_list by using a while loop to go through the array and assign each value to 0. (3) yes the blank is included as well and seeing it is the largest match then the score is 5. (4) yes the blank is considered. (5) it would still be 5 because " down" matches " down". Even if going through the string and at most only 1 letter matched, it would give a score of 1.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So how should I explicitly initialize it?

Comment: Re (1) the compiler complains, but given the context, a value from `scores_list[]` will be copied into `maximum`.  However, `scores_list[]` is not reliably initialized; you could do that with `char scores_list[15] = "";`, probably just inside the loop rather than outside it as at the moment.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but why does reading the lines by a loop give random characters? and also I should change my initialization for score_list by just adding = ""? I did that and nothing actually changed.

Comment: I've not made head or tail of the searching algorithm; it is a modestly complex problem you've set yourself, or been set.  I haven't thought about how I'd do it, either.  Probably something like search line for any character in the string (`strcspn()` or `strpbrk()`, I think), and then when I found one, analyze how long a string starts at that point (iteration over query string in some shape or form).

Comment: the posted code is far far from compiling.  Strongly suggest 1) since this is a runtime problem, post code that cleanly compiles and produces an executable that shows the problem.   Always enable all warnings when compiling (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: @user3629249 added the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue is in your design of `read_lines` and the `while` loop where it is called in `print_lines`. You cannot return either (1) `line_len`, or (2) `EOF` and test for `EOF` in your `while` loop because the two are *not* mutually exclusive. For example, and all too often, you have a file that fails to have a `newline` following the text on the last line. (POSIX specifies all files shall have an ending `newline`, but many editors will happily write files without it). If this occurs and you are testing `EOF` in your loop, you have missed the entire last line of text.

In addition, you are not testing if you have read more than `MAX_LINE` characters anywhere. To fix this problem, you can redesign `read_lines` to something like:

```
int read_lines (char line[MAX_LINE])
{
    int line_len = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar ()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        line[line_len] = c;
        line_len++;
        if (line_len == MAX_LINE - 1) break;
    }
    line[line_len] = 0;

    if (line_len)
        printf ("%s\n", line);

    return line_len ? line_len : c == EOF ? EOF : line_len;
}
```

Next, and in addition to all the good reasons given in the comments about compiling *with* warnings, you are making the code impossible to read by cramming it altogether without spaces or comments. You are also not handling your loop limits is a concise manner. Where the length of `query` exceeds `line`, you loop continually in your outer loop after reading the last character in `line` without doing anything. A simple:

```
int query_len = strlen (query);
...
int limit = query_len > line_len ? line_len : query_len;
```

will set the limit for a single loop that you can use to compute `score`, etc. (**note:** all your length `int` variables, should really be type `size_t` or `unsigned`, because you cannot have negative length. the same is true for counters holding only positive values, like your loop counters...)

Then for the actual processing, in order to handle all cases for the last line text, you can restructure your loop to something like:

```
    // while ((line_len = read_lines (line)) != EOF) 
    for (;;)
    {
        line_len = read_lines (line);
        c = 0;       /* this is important */

        if (line_len != EOF)
        {
            line_num++;
            printf ("S1: line   %d, bytes = %d \n", line_num, line_len);

            for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) 
            {
                 ...  /* rest of your loop here */
            }
        }

        if (line_len == EOF)
            break;
    }
```

You next have a big issue zeroing `score_list`. It only happens on the first loop iteration. Why? You never reset `c = 0;` after running:

```
    while (c < 15){
        score_list[c] = 0;
        c++;
    }
```

Meaning `score_list` is reset on the first pass, but then for every subsequent pass, `c` is already `15` and that code never executes.

If you take care of these issues, you can probably have your code do what you want. It is worth saying again, when compiling, compile with **warnings enabled**. At least `-Wall -Wextra`. Then fix all warnings. Give it a try and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < limit; i++){  
    for (y = 0; y < line_len; y++){  
        if (query[i] == line[y]){  
            score++;  
        }  
        else if(score != 0 && query[i] != line[y]){  
  score_list[z] = score;  
  z++;  
         }  
}  
}`

would this be the loop to use? and also i get an error.
`'line_len' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    int limit = query_len  > line_len ? line_len : query_len;`

Comment: I don't really understand the limit that I need to initialize.

Comment: All the `limit` does is look at the `strlen` of `query` and `line` and limits the loop iteration to the *lesser* of the two. (you can only read and compare that many characters when computing `score`)  In your code, look what happens when `line` is much shorter than `query` in `print_lines`. What happens with the value of `i`? And yes, **initialize all variables**. Initialize to `0` or `NULL` if nothing else, this includes arrays (e.g. `={0};` or `={NULL};`.

Comment: It now initializes but the score still stays at 0 for every line

Comment: Edit your question and post your current code for `print_lines` at the bottom of your question (don't change your original question). I suspect you still need more work there, but I can't guess at what you have.

Comment: @zkvsl after you added `limit`, you don't need the `y` loop anymore. Just get rid of `for (y = 0; y < limit; y++)` and compare `query[i] == line[i]`. That was the whole point of `limit` (to limit the characters checked to only characters common to both `query` and `line`) (unless you are comparing **any** common characters regardless of position -- then keep the `y` loop).

Comment: OK, I think I see what you are doing with `score` and it is a trainwreck. You do not limit `z` and you are smashing your stack when `z` exceeds `15` by writing beyond the end of `score_list`. Further, `score_list` should not be `char` it should be `int`. The same for `score`. With `score` as a `double` type promotion is likely adding to your problem. Go back and rewrite your entire `score` code with proper `types` and only use floating point for the final computation.